# If my account on Telerik AppBuilder expires, will my application in the market still work?

Tags: jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, telerik-appbuilder

I have created an app in the Telerik AppBuilder. My account is a free trial membership account valid for 30 days.
What will happen to the apps I submitted to the market after my trial expires?
Is there any need to continue my membership beyond the trial?

Answer (score 2):

Your app will continue to function, unless you are using any of the Telerik Platform runtime services like Backend Services, push notifications, responsive images, analytics, feedback, etc. Those services will terminate at the end of your trial.

Comment: I am not using any of these services my application is offline only related to play audios which are in the application.